# In C#, when a variable passes through a function/method, will the original variable change?

Tags: c#, oop, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am confused by how a function can change a variable passed through it. For example, if I created a variable t = 1, and pass a function by adding 2 to it, inside the function t is 3, but in Main function t is still 1:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int t = 1;
    addTwo(t);
    Console.WriteLine(t); 
    ## t=1
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static void addTwo(int t)
{
    t+=2;
    Console.WriteLine("inside function {0}",t); 
    ## t=3
```

the value of t inside the function is 3, but in Main the value stays 1.

However if I created an array "happiness" with value {2,3,4,5,6} and passed through a function "SunIsShining" which will increase each value by 2. Afterwards, I thought the array happiness should still be {2,3,4,5,6}. However it became {4,5,6,7,8}.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] happiness = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    SunIsShining(happiness);
    ## happiness = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }

    foreach (int y in happiness)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static void SunIsShining(int[] x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        x[i] += 2;
}
```

Could anyone help me to understand the reason? Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters

Comment: Note that while you can change the values in the array if you did `x = new int[0];` in the method, `happiness` would not be changed to an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in semantics between your two examples is not explained by the different types, but rather by you doing different things to the parameter in your two examples.

In the first example, you are assigning to the parameter (`t += 2` is equivalent to `t = t + 2`. `t = something` is assignment to `t`.) In the second example, you do not assign to `x`; rather, you are using the array element syntax to modify the internal contents of the array pointed to by `x`. If you did the same thing you did in your first example in your second example, i.e. assign directly to the parameter `x`, you would see that the called scope is similarly not affected by the assignment:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int[] happiness = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    SunIsShining(happiness);

    foreach (int y in happiness) {
        Console.WriteLine(y); // prints 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    }
}
static void SunIsShining(int[] x) {
    x = new int[] {7, 8, 9};
}
```

So despite your first example passing `int`, a value type, and this example passing `int[]`, a reference type, you can see that the result of assigning to the parameter in the called function is the same in both cases. And in fact this is true for all other types too -- if the method parameter is not marked `ref` or `out`, then no matter what type the parameter is, direct assignment to that parameter variable in the called function will never have any effect on a passed variable in the calling function.

Passing a variable to a method parameter that is not `ref` or `out` is exactly like assigning to a new variable. So rather than thinking about passing to methods, you can just think about what happens when you assign to a new variable. When you do this for your first example, you assign one `int` to another. Since `int` is a value type, each int variable holds its own integer, and assignment copies the integer so both variables' integers have the same value. Then when you assign to the second variable, you change that integer, but it doesn't affect the first variable's integer. This is pretty easy to understand.

```
int tInMain = 1;

int tInAddTwo = tInMain;
tInAddTwo += 2;
Console.WriteLine("inside function {0}", tInAddTwo); // prints 3

Console.WriteLine(tInMain); // prints 1
```

If you do this with my example above, you see we assign one `int[]` variable to another. `int[]` is a reference type, so the value of such a variable is a "reference" (basically, in C++ parlance, a pointer to an object). When you copy one reference to another, you get two references that have the same value, i.e. they both point to the same object. When you then assign a reference to another object to one of the variables, you just make that variable point to that other object. It does not do anything to the object that it used to point to (which the first variable still points to).

```
int[] happiness = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

int[] x = happiness;
x = new int[] {7, 8, 9};

foreach (int y in happiness) {
    Console.WriteLine(y); // prints 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
}
```

And if you do this with your second example, you see that you again assign one reference to another, so you have two reference variables pointing to the same object. But then you use one of those references to make a change to the contents of the object that is pointed to. This change is then obviously visible when you look at the object pointed to by the other reference, since it's the same object that is being pointed to.

```
int[] happiness = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

int[] x = happiness;
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    x[i] += 2;

foreach (int y in happiness)
{
    Console.WriteLine(y); // prints 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
}
```

Now you might ask why you can't do something like this with your first example. The reason is that the operation you are doing, i.e. "modify the object pointed to by the reference", simply doesn't exist for the type `int`. Most obviously, this is because `int` is a value type. But even for reference types, you might not be able to do this, because the object that is being pointed to might not offer you a way to modify its contents. For example, consider the following example where we box the `int` into an object variable of type `object`:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    object t = 1;
    addTwo(t);
    Console.WriteLine(t); // prints 1
}
static void addTwo(object t) { // <-- object is a reference type
    // there is nothing you can do to t here
    // that will change what is printed in Main

    // as described above, assignment to t
    // will never affect the calling scope:
    t = (int)t + 2;
}
```

This is similar to your first example, except that the parameter type is `object`, a reference type (the type of references to objects). But this object that the `int` is boxed into simply does not offer a way for you to modify its contents. So even though in this case, you passed a reference, and the `t` in `addTwo` and the `t` in `Main` point to a single object, it doesn't really matter since you can't make a change to that object that can be seen through the other reference.

Answer (score 4):

Because

- `int[]` is a reference type that might pass the object reference to the function, so you modify the value from the same array.
- `int` is a value type that will *clone* value before passing to the function, so you modify the value is not `t` from `Main` function.

We can prove by this sample code by `ReferenceEquals` method that will compare the object reference whether the same as below, let's say we can see `addTwo` is return `false`, but `SunIsShining` return true.

```
static int t1;
static int[] happiness;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    t1 = 1;
    happiness = new int[]{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    
    addTwo(t1);
    SunIsShining(happiness);
    
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static void addTwo(int t)
{   
    t+=2;
    Console.WriteLine("Is same object by value?" + object.ReferenceEquals(t1,t)); 
}

static void SunIsShining(int[] x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Is same object by refer?" + object.ReferenceEquals(happiness,x)); 
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

More information we can see

[value-types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)

[reference-types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

[passing-parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know where I can find the list of "reference type" and "value type", or any microsoft documents that introduce the difference between these two?

Comment: @Joey I had added more detail and refer document in my answer hope that can help you

Answer (score 1):

Variable passing is divided into value passing and address passing.
Value passing can't change the previous value, address passing is passing the address, so you can change the previous value.
For example, the first one is passed by the name of the variable. T stores an int, so it passes a data, so it passes a 1 in the function, independent of the t in Main.  Pass is the value
Behind;  We're passing the name of the array, and the name of the array is the address of the first element in the array, so we're passing the address, so we're accessing it by address, changing the original value

Comment: "passing the name of the array" isn't correct. That's not at all what happens.